# Temporarily disabling hardware IO ports for remote connection

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, script, c++, io

I'm using moonlight with sunshine to stream my desktop to my mobile devices for remote access.

Is there a way for a script to toggle the all IO ports, except the ethernet, on and off to prevent direct hardware access during the remote section?

Or as a easier alternative just blocking mouse and keyboard input of specific devices is enough

I've tried a few ways, ahk, devcon, pnputil, padlock, which either intercepts inputs at a layer too high, or requires a restart to disable/enable devices.

And if im not mistaken autolt also intercepts at a high layer, in which case the remote desktop will also be blocked.

I'm not optimistic that there exist a solution out there anymore, can someone guide me a bit on how to start tackling this problem?

A gui solution would be a bit tedious, but i can always scrap a part of its source code for personal use

Thanks.

Comment: What is your goal? Prevent that somebody uses the computer while you're logged in remotely?

Comment: Kind of, but losing physical access to a PC is already a serious security breach so its like a bicycle lock at best. The remote host is in my home so the answer should be yes. In theory im trying to achieve a headless machine toggle with a script.

Comment: I don't know the tool you're using there, but many remote tools (e.g. Remote Desktop) already come with this feature built-in.

Answer (score 0):

Moonlight/Sunlight is not a proper remote access solution.
It is a game streaming solution and as such it lacks the ability to lockdown the server system.
In most streaming solutions that is intentional as the streaming software itself in most cases needs that access in order to do its job.

If your intend is to use this truly as a game-streaming setup you will have to live with it.
If you real intend is to have a Remote Desktop setup, then use a proper remote access solution (e.g Remote Desktop, AnyDesk, TeamViewer, just to name a few) instead.
And you can have both types of service available so you can switch as needed.

Comment: Hm well, thats question tactical failure on me. Sunshine is the best remote desktop utility among all due to its superior latency, security, flexibility, and its open source. So if anything i would like to stick with sunshine.

Comment: One extra thing, Im on a ios device, UltraVNC does exactly what i want but i need a headless proxy at best. which wont work as of the latency.